# Sort an Array and get the 3 largest element 

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am beginner java programmer. 
I have this homework: Write a static method, in the parameter of method is an Drink array. The method returns with the 3 largest alcohol drink array element.

**My question is: Is there a shorter solution as I wrote?**

```
    public static void alcoholMax(AlcoholDrink[] t){
    // sort the AlcoholDrink[] t
    Arrays.sort(t, new Comparator<AlcoholDrink>() { 
        // here I try sorting the elements by their alcohol value
        @Override
        public int compare(AlcoholDrink o1, AlcoholDrink o2) {
            int at1 = (int)o1.getAlcohol(); // get the alcohol value
            int at2 = (int)o2.getAlcohol(); // get the alcohol value
            if(at1>at2)
                return -1;
            else if(at1<at2 )
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });
    // get the 3 largest element of the sorted array
    double t0 = t[0].getAlcohol();
    double t1 = t[1].getAlcohol();
    double t2 = t[2].getAlcohol();
    // check, 1st > 2nd > 3rd, if this not true, return with null reference
    if(t0>t1 && t1>t2)
        System.out.println(t[0] + "\n" + t[1] + "\n" + t[2]);
    else
        System.out.println("null");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    AlcoholDrink[] t = new AlcoholDrink [8];
    // new AlcoholDrink( String Name, String Stripping, int price, double alcohol)
    // these are hungarian wines :). If somebody curious for the languange
    t[0] = new AlcoholDrink("Kék Portói", "0.75 l", 1200, 20.5);
    t[1] = new AlcoholDrink("Kék Oportó", "0.75 l", 1100, 10.5);
    t[2] = new AlcoholDrink("Tokaji Asszú", "0.75 l ", 1600, 14.5);
    t[3] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Bikavér", "0.75 l", 1500, 23.5);      
    t[4] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Leányka", "0.75 l", 1100, 8.5);
    t[5] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Merlot", "0.75 l", 1700, 18.5);
    t[6] = new AlcoholDrink("Egri Medina", "0.75 l", 900, 16.5);
    t[7] = new AlcoholDrink("Törley Talisman", "0.75 l", 750, 4.5);     

    alcoholMax(t);
    // It is always return with "null"
```

Comment: Ok, I know... I have to change the return values :) in the if cases :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `getAlcohol()` method returns a double, then, you should not cast it to an `int`, this will cause a loss of precision. Also, you can compare doubles automatically instead of doing it yourself, like so:

```
Arrays.sort(t, new Comparator<AlcoholDrink>() { 
        // here I try sorting the elements by their alcohol value
        @Override
        public int compare(AlcoholDrink o1, AlcoholDrink o2) {
           return o1.getAlcohol().compareTo(o2.getAlcohol());
        }
    });
```

You can also make your `Alcohol` class implement the `Comparable` Interface as shown in [this](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-comparable-interface.html) example.

Lastly, if you want to stick to your own code, you might want to consider making a change to the value returned by the compare method like so:

```
 @Override
        public int compare(AlcoholDrink o1, AlcoholDrink o2) {
            int at1 = (int)o1.getAlcohol(); // get the alcohol value
            int at2 = (int)o2.getAlcohol(); // get the alcohol value
            if(at1>at2)
                return -1;
            else if(at1<at2 )
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }
```

I can't test the code at the moment, but you might be sorting the array in an ascending fashion.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the Comparable interface at Alcohol class, but the prof said: we must only implement the o1.name.compareto(o2.name) logic, and mustn't use the o1.getAlcohol().compareTo(o2.getAlcohol());

Comment: In that case, you could move the sorting logic to the Alcohol class and then call .Sort(t). That should have the same effect. Also, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it so :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array is being sorted in ascending order I believe.

In that case, you want to get the last 3 elements after the sort, or change your comparator.

Answer (score 0):

in your comparator, return -1 if it is less than, 1 if it is greater than and that should work

Answer (score 0):

```
First sort the array descending order and get the first three element.

package sortingelementinarray;
public class SortElement 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int array[] = {1,6,4,7,2,3};
        int temp;
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array.length; j++)
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(array[j] > array[i])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;

            }
        }
        }
        for(int abc : array)
        {
            System.out.println(abc);
        }

    }
}
```