# Array of the 3 largest numbers

Tags: java

I was working on a method trying to create a array that will contain the 3 largest numbers. But there is an error in my code and I couldn't understand what I did wrong. Thanks!

public class Method3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a={2,5,6,7,9,1,2,3,5,9,7};

    System.out.print(largestSum(a));


}


public static int[] largestSum(int[] a){

    int temp, first, second, third;
    first=second=third=a[0];

    for(int element: a){

        if(first < element)
            {
                temp=first;
                first=element;
                second=temp;
            }

        if(second<element && first> element)
            {

                temp=element;
                second=element;
                third=temp;
            }

        if(third< element && second> element)
            {
            temp=element;
            third=element;

            }

    }

    int [] array=new int[3];
    array[0]=first;
    array[1]=second;
    array[3]=third;



    return array;
}
```

}

Comment: You can use [Arrays#sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) to help you with this if it isn't homework.

Comment: use sort and then take 3 last elements in array (or first if sort is descending)

Comment: with the naming convention of the code it appears that its homework but anyway i think sorting integers is already in sort method and you can just check if array length is greater than 3 then return top 3 else return array itself after sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort an Array and get the 3 largest element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020749/sort-an-array-and-get-the-3-largest-element)

Answer (score 2):

You missed some cases: And you cannot initalize `first`, `second` and `third` all with `a[0]` because this value is only valid once.

```
first=second=third=Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int element: a){
    if(first <= element){
            third=second;
            second=first;
            first=element;
            continue;
    }
    if(second <= element ){
            third=second;
            second=element;
            continue;
    }
    if(third < element){
            third=element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few of issues with what you have. You set all the values to `a[0]` that means if `a[0]` is the largest it will never get updated. When you update the first largest you lose the second value not the 3rd. And you are setting array[3] which is invalid for a 3 element array.

Try.

```
  public static int[] largestSum(int[] a)
  {
    int largest[3] = {Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
       if(a[i] > largest[0])
       {
          largest[2] = largest[1];
          largest[1] = largest[0];
          largest[0] = a[i];
       }
       else if(a[i] > largest[1])
       {
          largest[2] = largest[1];
          largest[1] = a[i];
       }
       else if(a[i] > largest[2])
       {
         largest[2] = a[i];
       }
    }

    return largest;
 }
```

Comment: make sure you put all this in an if statement for array length greater than 3 or else it will raise eyebrows on index not found.

Comment: largest[2] = largest[1]; will fail if length is 2. But fair enough you  should not call this method if you have 2 or less elements.

Comment: I understand but anyway I'm assuming that the array has 3 or more elements.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani largest is always length 3. It just means that at least one of the values will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`